# Is it possible to edit items loaded by jquery through javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm building a static commerce website as part of one of my modules. My intention is for the navigation bar items to change when hovered over.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var aboutus = document.getElementById("aboutus");
    var gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");
    var tips = document.getElementById("tips");
    var contactus = document.getElementById("contactus");
    var ourstores = document.getElementById("ourstores");
    
    *aboutus.onmouseenter = function(){this.style.backgroundColor = "gray"; this.style.color = "gold"; this.style.borderStyle = "outset";};*
    aboutus.onmouseleave = function(){this.style.backgroundColor = "white"; this.style.color = "black"; this.style.borderStyle = "inset";};

........}
```

This works perfectly well on the index page, but breaks on the other pages. I'm sure it's linked to me using jquery to create a template for all of the linked pages. For example, my 'About Us' Page:

```
<body>
    <div id="AUmenubar">
       <script>
            $("#AUmenubar").load("index.html #mainmenubar");
        </script>
    
    </div>

    <div id="AUcontactus">
        <script>
            $("#AUcontactus").load("index.html #contactustab");
        </script>
    </div>
    <script src="javaworks.js"></script>
</body>
```

The elements all load in correctly, and everything look the same on inspect. But, as I've already said, the effects detailed in the JavaScript doesn't do the graphic I'm trying to programme. I get the following error: "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onmouseenter')
at window.onload (javaworks.js:8:26)**". I've tried all sorts of code restructuring and I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: #aboutus does not exist either at the moment you try to get it, or simply not on that page. Also, mouseenter & mouseleaver is just called a 'hover'.

Comment: `window.onload` runs when the DOM has loaded (more-or-less) - but at that same point your `.load()` ajax call will not have completed.   I suggest moving the inline-scripts to the bottom and using the callback from `.load(url, callback)` to add the events.

Comment: Using the callback worked like a charm! Thank you for the suggestion. And yeah there's hover but I have lots of JS next year so practice is needed.